Changing path in Python without leaving virtual environment
I have a program in Python that activates the virtual environment and then returns to project folder and executes the main project file:
os.chdir('venv/Scripts')
os.system('activate')
os.chdir('../../')
os.system('python main.py')

But this code has a problem. It works fine until os.system('activate'), but when I change the path and go back to the project folder to run the file, the program automatically exits the virtual environment that I had activated, and the project doesn't run properly.
I tried the following code instead of os.chdir but it didn't work:
os.system('cd ../../')

This code doesn't even change the path.

What happens if you don't use os.chdir and instead use os.system('venv/Scripts/activate') and then os.system('python main.py')?

@mkrieger1
This code is executed in Windows cmd, and when you write this code, the activate file isn't executed, and cmd thinks that this is a command, and because it doesn't recognize it, it gives an error.
